# Comparator function in sort() method c++. Getting different solution for large array of numbers

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14

Unable to understand Comparator function behaviour when sorting an array of 1000 elements with value 1000000 in descending order. (The array is 1 indexed)

The first instance of definition of comparator function has random
zeroes at some indexes in the array.

The second instance of definition of comparator function works fine.
Could anyone explain why this is happening

```
bool func(long long a, long long b){
  return (a >= b);
}
```

```
sort (A+1, A + 1000 + 1, func);
```

---

```
bool func(long long a, long long b){
  return (a > b);
}
```

```
sort (A+1, A + 1000 + 1, func);
```

Output 1:
1000000 1000000 1000000 0 0 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000

Output 2:
1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000

Comment: Read about [compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). Your version with `>=` doesn't satisfy strict weak ordering requirements, it leads to UB.

Comment: You should use `b < a` in your former code.

Answer (score 4):

When you pass custom comparison functions to `std::sort`, they must induce what is called a "strict weak ordering relation" (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)). Your function

```
bool func(long long a, long long b){
  return (a >= b);
}
```

does not satisfy these requirement (e.g. `func(42, 42) != false`). This result in undefined behavior, the resulting sequence can by anything.

Comment: Just to add that, more specifically, the algorithm _assumes_ that your ordering satisfies that requirement, and will not keep checking that assumption along the way (because that would be slow) - we could probably work out which exact step of the algorithm falls foul of your error and how exactly this results in trouble, but we generally do not bother because (a) it would take time, and (b) it would not help us fix the problem.

Comment: The key is that, in this context, `>=` is not the opposite of `<` (possibly unintuitive at first glance!)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are observing is due to sorting equal values.
If you have a sequence `3 3 3 3 4` and try to sort it, the algorithm using only `>=` (or any other equal sign) can not distinguish what order the number should be placed.

In my previous example, when it's comparing the first `3` with the second one, the compare function says the first is less than the second. Then if for whatever reason, it's trying to compare the second with the first, the same function will say that the second is less than the first. This confuses the algorithm and make it undefined behavior.

Because of this, the standard expect you provide a compare function that's not ambiguous. It's easy in your case, just use the operator without equality:

```
inline bool func(long long a, long long b) { return b < a; }
```

Please notice that if the algorithm needs to know if two value are equal, it needs to call your function twice (`bool isEqual(a,b) = !func(a,b) && !func(b,a)`).
It's not optimal (2 tests instead of one), so that's why the spaceship operator was added in C++20.